# Не получается записать координаты в input box

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, google-maps, marker

Используя Google Map API, наткнулся на небольшую проблему, у меня не получается изменить данные в тэг `Input`. Создал маркер которую можно передвигать в нужное мне место.
Задача у меня такая: при передвижении маркера в нужное мне место, менялись и координаты в `input`. 
Как это реализовать?? Или есть другие альтернативные методы?

При запуске страницы, в `input` вводятся начальные координаты `myCenter`

Можете взглянуть как работает..

```js
var map;
    var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(40.4092481, 49.8670721);
    function initialize() {
        var mapProp = {
            center: myCenter,
            zoom: 12,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myCenter,
            draggable: true,
            title: "Передвинь меня!"
        });
        marker.setMap(map);
        var a = myCenter.lat();
        var b = myCenter.lng();
        document.add_point.latitude.value=a;
        document.add_point.longitude.value=b;

    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```html
<form role="form" name="add_point" class="text-center">
  <div class="form-group">
  <label>Coordinates</label><br>
LAT: <input class="coordinate form-control" id="lat" name="latitude" type="text"
            placeholder="You can select on map">
LNG: <input class="coordinate form-control" id="lng" name="longitude" type="text"
            placeholder="You can select on map">
   </div>
  </form>
                <div class="center-block" id="googleMap" style="width:auto;height:500px; border-radius: 6px"></div>

<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCyByXI8TPQnG5RpKPJ-ISSFFpcDpXhFoA"></script>
```

Как сделать так чтобы, при изменении места маркера, менялись соответственно и его координаты?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Достаточно добавить обработку событий `drag` и `dragend`

```
marker.addListener('drag', onDragOrDragend);
marker.addListener('dragend', onDragOrDragend);
```

Обработчик:

```
function onDragOrDragend(e) {
    document.getElementById('lat').value = e.latLng.lat();
    document.getElementById('lng').value = e.latLng.lng();
}
```

Полный код примера:

```js
var map;
var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(40.4092481, 49.8670721);

function initialize() {
  var mapProp = {
    center: myCenter,
    zoom: 12,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myCenter,
    draggable: true,
    title: "Передвинь меня!"
  });
  marker.setMap(map);
  marker.addListener('drag', onDragOrDragend);
  marker.addListener('dragend', onDragOrDragend);

  var a = myCenter.lat();
  var b = myCenter.lng();
  document.add_point.latitude.value = a;
  document.add_point.longitude.value = b;

}

function onDragOrDragend(e) {
  document.getElementById('lat').value = e.latLng.lat();
  document.getElementById('lng').value = e.latLng.lng();
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```html
<form role="form" name="add_point" class="text-center">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Coordinates</label><br> LAT: <input class="coordinate form-control" id="lat" name="latitude" type="text" placeholder="You can select on map"> LNG: <input class="coordinate form-control" id="lng" name="longitude" type="text" placeholder="You can select on map">
  </div>
</form>
<div class="center-block" id="googleMap" style="width:auto;height:500px; border-radius: 6px"></div>

<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCyByXI8TPQnG5RpKPJ-ISSFFpcDpXhFoA"></script>
```

Comment: Оооо)) Точняк) Спасибо)